# Insert a value from a table in another table as foreign key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, auto-increment

I have two tables, `cinema` and `theater`.

**Table Cinema**

Columns:
`id, name, is_active`

**Table Theater**

Columns:
`id, cinema_id`

I'm doing insertion into the DB, in sequence. First, I'll insert into `cinema` and then into `theater`. The `cinema_id.theater` is a foreign key that reference `cinema.id`. After the insertion into `cinema`, I'll insert data into the `theater`, but I need the value from cinema's `id` before insert the data in `cinema_id`.

I was thinking about `RETURNING id INTO cinema_id` and, then, save into `theater`. But I really don't know how I can possibly do something like this.

Any thoughts? Is there any better way to do something like this?

Comment: You can't get id like that. You have to query tableA get the latest inserted record and get the id and then insert into TableB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

The first one is using the `lastval()` function which returns the value of the last generated sequence value:

```
insert into cinema(name, is_active) values ('Cinema One', true); 
insert into theater(cinema_id) values (lastval());
```

Alternatively you can pass the sequence name to the `currval()` function:

```
insert into theater(cinema_id) 
values (currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('cinema', 'id')));
```

Alternatively you can chain the two statements using a CTE and the returning clause:

```
with new_cinema as (
   insert into cinema (name, is_active)   
   values ('Cinema One', true)
   returning id
)
insert into theater (cinema_id)
select id
from new_cinema;
```

In both statements I assume `theater.id` is also a generated value.

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it became clearer now.
Also, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks. This will work. 
But, for example, if I have to add the value from another table inside `theater`, the `lastval()` wouldn't work, right? Would I had to go for the second method?

Comment: `lastval()` uses the generated value from the last statement, so if you run both statements right after each other within the same connection it will work just fine. Alternatively you can pass the sequence name.

Comment: Hey, another question. If I have a table using the Unique constraints (Unique()), I'd have to go for the `with new_cinema ...`, right? Since the `currval()` or `lastval()` won't work anymore.

Comment: The use of `currval()` has nothing to do with unique constraints, but please ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

this way works.

```
with new_cinema as (
   insert into cinema (name, is_active)   
   values ('Cinema One', true)
   returning id
)
insert into theater (cinema_id)
select id
from new_cinema;
```

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO tableB
(
    columnA
)
SELECT
    columnA
FROM
    tableA
ORDER BY columnA desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please consider adding a description of your code so we know what it does and why.

Comment: This is not correct, just picking the "latest" row from that table is not necessarily the one that just go inserted. Chances are high that this is the case, but if the e.g. the primary key isn't actually an integer (but e.g. a `uuid`) this would insert the completely wrong value.